# cant attach to VM: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: no providers installed

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I'm trying to put a java agent on the running process. My issue is i cannot attach to the VM because i get the following error:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider: Provider sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: no providers installed
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:203)
    at io.github.giantnuker.tailor.transform.JavaAgent.attachAgent(JavaAgent.java:31)
```

The important part appearsto be `com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: no providers installed`

This is the class that produces the error:

```java
public class JavaAgent {
    public static void agentmain(String stringArguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        System.out.println("hi from agentmain");
    }

    private static String getPid() {
        RuntimeMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        String pid = bean.getName();
        if (pid.contains("@")) {
            pid = pid.substring(0, pid.indexOf("@"));
        }
        return pid;
    }

    public static void attachAgent() {
        try {
            System.out.println("PID is " + getPid());
            VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(getPid());
            Properties props = vm.getSystemProperties();
            vm.loadAgent(new File(JavaAgent.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()).getAbsolutePath());
            vm.detach();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("attach");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        attachAgent();
    }
}
```

Line 31 of the class is `VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(getPid());`

Any clues? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you running a JRE and not a JDK installation of the JVM?

Comment: nope its a jdk @RafaelWinterhalter

Comment: Maybe the attach library is already loaded elsewhere? What answer does the VM provide if you step through the code?